# replace css animation without changing the position of the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my code

https://jsfiddle.net/sameh0/hgk2uLfk/2/

I want to change the animation of `rightleft` when hovering over the div. However when I do that, the position of the div gets back first and then changes the animation which creates a bad interaction experience.

That being said I'm open to add any JS/JQuery code.

Currently when the div is hovered it's stopped in its initial position and the new animation `bubble` takes place.

MY GOAL IS :
to make the div stop at it's current position and the new animation `bubble` starts while the div is stopped .

and this is the code 
HTML

```
<div class="circle"></div>
```

CSS

```
 .circle{
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  cursor: pointer;
  top:25%;
   left :28%;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  -webkit-animation: rightleft 2.5s infinite alternate cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.03, 0.515, 0.955) , bubble 2s infinite alternate cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.03, 0.515, 0.955);
  -moz-animation: rightleft 2.5s infinite alternate cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.03, 0.515, 0.955),bubble 2s infinite alternate cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.03, 0.515, 0.955);
  animation: rightleft 2.5s infinite alternate cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.03, 0.515, 0.955),bubble 2s infinite alternate cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.03, 0.515, 0.955) ;
background-color:blue;
  background-size: 80%;
}
.circle:hover{
  background-color:red;
   -webkit-animation: bubble, 0.8s infinite alternate  cubic-bezier(0.46, 0.03, 1, 0.21) !important;
  -moz-animation: bubble 0.8s infinite alternate  cubic-bezier(0.46, 0.03, 1, 0.21) !important;
  animation:  bubble 0.8s infinite alternate  cubic-bezier(0.46, 0.03, 1, 0.21) !important;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rightleft {
  0% {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  }

  100% {
    margin-left: -30px;
    margin-top: -30px;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes rightleft {
  0% {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  }

  100% {
    margin-left: -30px;
    margin-top: -30px;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes rightleft {
  0% {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  }

  100% {
    margin-left: -30px;
    margin-top: -30px;
  }
}

@keyframes rightleft {
  0% {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  }

  100% {
    margin-left: -30px;
    margin-top: -30px;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes bubble {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.9);
    transform: scale(0.9);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes bubble {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.9);
    transform: scale(0.9);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes bubble {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.9);
    transform: scale(0.9);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
}

@keyframes bubble {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.9);
    transform: scale(0.9);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like something can be done by nesting divs based on [this CSS-Tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/controlling-css-animations-transitions-javascript/#article-header-id-11) and [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/BseLV/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about the following code?

```
.circle{
  background-color:blue;
  animation:
    rightleft 2.5s infinite alternate cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.03, 0.515, 0.955),
    bubble 2s infinite alternate cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.03, 0.515, 0.955) ;
}

.circle:hover{
  background-color:red;
  animation:
    rightleft 2.5s infinite alternate cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.03, 0.515, 0.955),
    bubble 0.8s infinite alternate  cubic-bezier(0.46, 0.03, 1, 0.21);
  animation-play-state: paused, running;
}

@keyframes rightleft {
  0% {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -100px;
    margin-top: -100px;
  }
}

@keyframes bubble {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.9);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/hgk2uLfk/7/)

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/hgk2uLfk/10/

Updated

```
<div class="circle">
  <div class="bubble"></div>
</div>



.circle{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  top:25%;
  left :28%;
  -webkit-animation: rightleft 2.5s infinite alternate cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.03, 0.515, 0.955) , bubble 2s infinite alternate cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.03, 0.515, 0.955);
  -moz-animation: rightleft 2.5s infinite alternate cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.03, 0.515, 0.955),bubble 2s infinite alternate cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.03, 0.515, 0.955);
  animation: rightleft 2.5s infinite alternate cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.03, 0.515, 0.955),bubble 2s infinite alternate cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.03, 0.515, 0.955) ;
}

.circle:hover {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
  -o-animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

.bubble {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color:blue;
  background-size: 80%;
}

.bubble:hover{
  background-color:red;
  -webkit-animation: bubble, 0.8s infinite alternate  cubic-bezier(0.46, 0.03, 1, 0.21) !important;
  -moz-animation: bubble 0.8s infinite alternate  cubic-bezier(0.46, 0.03, 1, 0.21) !important;
  animation:  bubble 0.8s infinite alternate  cubic-bezier(0.46, 0.03, 1, 0.21) !important;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rightleft {
  0% {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  }

  100% {
    margin-left: -30px;
    margin-top: -30px;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes rightleft {
  0% {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  }

  100% {
    margin-left: -30px;
    margin-top: -30px;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes rightleft {
  0% {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  }

  100% {
    margin-left: -30px;
    margin-top: -30px;
  }
}

@keyframes rightleft {
  0% {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  }

  100% {
    margin-left: -30px;
    margin-top: -30px;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes bubble {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.9);
    transform: scale(0.9);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes bubble {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.9);
    transform: scale(0.9);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes bubble {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.9);
    transform: scale(0.9);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
}

@keyframes bubble {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.9);
    transform: scale(0.9);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Nope , i want to make the div stop at it's current position and the new animation `bubble` starts while the div is stopped .
you made the 'rightleft' animation keep going even when the div is hovered , i don't want that behavior . 
i updated the question for more clarification of what i want . 
Thanks for responding .

Comment: Sorry, link to fiddle change on update (as opposite to codepen). Now its correct.

Comment: it's almost perfect . 
just added that

  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused,running;
  -moz-animation-play-state: paused,running;
  -o-animation-play-state:  paused,running;
  animation-play-state:  paused,running;

Answer (score 0):

add this code to the previous code and it will work

```
.circle:hover {
animation-name: rightleft;
animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

Comment: when ever i hover the ball keeps running from me ! 
GeckoTang answer is almost as same as you but without the strange ball behavior .